# Exporting a Database using Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: database, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've done a database using **Oracle SQL Developer** for a University exam. Now, I've to send it to my Professor by email.

It's possible to export the database completely as one directory, containing all files I've created, in order to allow my Professor to import it into SQL Developer and test it?

I've tried using "Tools">"Database Export" but I've obtained only a lot of separate files.

Comment: Did your professor not provide instructions?  What do you mean by "database"?  The entire oracle database including all the schemas and meta-data, or just table rows for a set of tables that your professor already has created?

Comment: Hello OldProgrammer! The first one, an entire Oracle DB. Unfortunately, I've not received instructions about exporting projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong, I'm afraid. You've (tried to) export just one **schema**, not entire database.

---

Anyway: if you got bunch of files, then it is because you instructed the tool to do so. Next time choose **single file**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Littlefoot. I thought it was possible to get something like a ZIP file with the same files created but this solution seems just as good :) Have a good day!

Comment: Well, nobody prevents you to ZIP that file, if you want :) You're welcome.

Comment: Or choose separate files, specify a DIRECTORY, then zip that up.